# How can I fix the chrome and chromedriver version in heroku with python

Tags: python, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome and chromedriver as heroku buildpacks in heroku

If chrome or chromedriver's version is updated, it's not compatible

Then Do I have to look forward to another one's update?

I want to fix their version

currently, I am using that

1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

2 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
somebody help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and realized that this is an open issue in the repositories of both buildpacks:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/86
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver/issues/35

You can find some workarounds in these links but apparently there is no general fix at the moment. In my case, I only had to reset my cache. Using the heroku CLI:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30823111)

Comment: The essential part of the answer is that there is no general fix and I am providing the details of the solution that worked for me taken from one of the links. However, the discussion in the links shows that what worked for me does not work for everyone.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!